# Tablesize makes no sense between enviroments

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

We are currently building a GatewayAPi which hold some data required to intergrate with legacy grids.
This means these tables hold some bulk data until the legacy components are removed.

Our database for this is set in Azure, 1 in an Dev/Test subscription, 1 in an normal one.
Both running an elastic pool in which this database resides.

Currently our Acceptance gateway database hold 2 big tables, 1 (A) with 9.566.312 rows, totaling about 8888 MB and 1 (B) with 47.731.430 rows totaling about 20160 MB.

Now here is where it gets weird.
We moved this to the production enviroment and synced the data as well, now off course production holds more records, however the 2 tables grew exponentially.

When looking at the production database we have the following statistics.

Table A holds 19.151.064 and now has a total space of 32720 MB, 3.5 times more while the data only roughly doubles. Table B holds 59.908.850 rows and has a total space of 46615 MB 2.3 times more while only having 12 million more records.

Both acceptance and production have the same indexes added and seem to follow this logic as well. The NonClustered index on Table B also is 3.4 times bigger.

Am i missing something?

The schema of Table B (focussing on this one as this is the biggest)

```
CREATE TABLE [PriceHistory](
    [ProductId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductName] [nvarchar](1024) NOT NULL,
    [SearchValue] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [Subclass] [nvarchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [Brand] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [BasePrice] [decimal](18, 4) NOT NULL,
    [SalesLevel] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [ItemPrice] [decimal](18, 4) NOT NULL,
    [Factor] [decimal](18, 4) NOT NULL,
    [Rule] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [EffectiveUntil] [datetime] NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [CreateDateUTC] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PriceHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProductId] ASC,
    [SalesLevel] ASC,
    [CreateDateUTC] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCX_PriceHistory_CreateDateUTC] ON [PriceHistory]
(
    [CreateDateUTC] DESC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Did you try index rebuild?

Comment: As far as i know, an index rebuild does not reduce the size of the index but can even cause this to grow, so no i have not yet done that.

Comment: Where do you get that from? It shouldn't do that unless you have LOB data, in which case you use `REORGANIZE WITH ( LOB_COMPACTION = ON )` or you are doing it `ONLINE` which sometimes causes that also.

Comment: It's mainly what i found through various searches, however i will give it a try this week. As this is production it will need  to be done during the evening.